# Hibernate Validator annotations not working

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation, design-by-contract

I just added `hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar` to my classpath and annotated a POJO:

```
public class Person {
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    // etc...
}
```

Then I went to test it out with a driver:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setName(null);
    }
}
```

This executes without throwing any validation errors - where am I going awry?

Comment: You are just constructing a `Person` object plainly so there wouldn't be validation running on that object. How would Hibernate validation know about this object and that is was being null? It is the same as using other annotations. You should check out the getting started guide - http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should run the validation engine to check if it is valid or not:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setName(null);

      ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
      Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> constraints = factory.getValidator().validate(p);
        // constraint will have the results of validation

    }
}
```

You also need to add `javax.validation:validation-api` to your classpath.
Most of the frameworks do these validation logics behind the scene for avoiding boilerplate codes.

Comment: Your comment about the required validation-api package saved me a few more hours of debugging, thanks. What is the reason why it's needed?